# Java Regex Question - Ignore Quotations

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a program using regex. The format for an identifier, as I might have explained in another question of mine, is that it can only begin with a letter (and the rest of it can contain whatever). I have this part worked out for the most part.
However, anything within quotes cannot count as an identifier either.

Currently I am using `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*");` as my pattern, which indicates that the first character can only be letters. So how can I edit this to check if the word is surrounded by quotations (and EXCLUSE those words)?

Comment: Is this just old legacy ASCII data, or is it in fact actual Java character data and hence proper Unicode?  The property for a letter is `\pL`.  Java does not yet support the `\p{Quotation_Mark}` property, so you will have to cobble together something using things like `["'«»‘’‚‛“”„‟‹›]`.  This becomes tougher if you want them to be matching, of course. Also, Java’s `\b` is utterly broken.

Comment: @tchrist While I agree with you w.r.t. bad Unicode support in Java, I'd say the OP isn't interested in Unicode here. For me *identifier* is exactly the think described by the above regex and *quoted identifier* is one enclosed in U+0022 (at least when I work with program-like data).

Answer (score 3):

Use negative [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions:

```
"(?<!\")\\b[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\\b(?!\")"
```

Example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\")\\b[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\\b(?!\")");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Foo \"bar\" baz");
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
Foo
baz
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/w2u8j).

Comment: That only works on legacy ASCII data, not on Java’s native character set!!

Answer (score 2):

Use lookarounds.

```
"(?<![\"A-Za-z])[A-Z...
```

The `(?<![\"A-Za-z])` part means "if the previous character is not a quotation mark or a letter".